# Matlab vector operation (vector + vector (by element))

Tags: matlab, vector, operation

I know in Matlab you can use "nice" vector operations like `A*B` or `A.*B`

If you have

```
A=[2, 2];
B=[3, 1];
```

it is logic, you cannot use `A*B`. You can use `A.*B` what is `A[1]*B[1], A[2]*B[2]` and result is `[6, 2]`.

In many "scripts" I am writing I often need to use something, that results in:

```
[6, 6; 
2, 2]
```

So basically i need to use forcycle (something like:):

```
C=zeros(2,2);
for i=1:size(A,1)
  C(i,:)=A*B(i);
end
```

And i would like to ask, how (if it is possible) to rewrite this without forcycles? Is it possible?
This 2 vectors of 2 elements is maybe bad for understanding what i need.
So another example:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=[2,4]
```

result:

```
[2,4,6,8,10;
4,8,12,16,20]
```

in short SOMETHING like:
C(1:end <==== GO BY ONE ELEMENT,:)=A*B(1:end <===== GO BY ONE ELEMENT)
--> Take WHOLE vector A and multiply it by FIRST element in B and save it at FIRST row in matrix what have A columns and B rows..
--> Take WHOLE vector A and multiply it by SECOND element in B and save it at SECOND row in matrix what have A columns and B rows..
--> Take WHOLE vector A and multiply it by THIRD element in B and save it at THIRD row in matrix what have A columns and B rows..
--> ...
--> Take WHOLE vector A and multiply it by LAST element in B and save it at LAST row in matric what have A columns and B rows..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun` for this purpose

```
P = bsxfun(@times,A,B')
```

This gives

```
A =  1     2     3     4     5
B =  2     4


P =  2     4     6     8    10
     4     8    12    16    20
```

Comment: will try..thanks..bsxfun functions is something what i really dont understand and i thought there will be a solution..got a try that..thanks

Comment: exactly what i needed to do..works like a charm..thanks you very much..and can you please advice me a little bit more..do you have some link where bsx functions are good explained that i can maybe try to understand them?? again thank you very much. answer found..

Comment: To understand such function, you probably need to play with toy examples. Here, `bsxfun` uses the column vector of B (`B'`), takes one element at a time (first of B then second), and apply for each of them the `times` function (A times one value of B).

Comment: Remember to use `.'`, not `'`. The vectors could be complex!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to use matrix multiplication:

```
[ones(size(B))'*A].*[B'*ones(size(A))]
```

Comment: Nice solution as well. But i think we both can agree, bsxfun is a little bit nicer solution (atleast for writing it :D)..Is there some advantages in this alternative?? For example better computing time or better memory performance?

Comment: I agree, bsxfun is probably better both in brevity and speed. The only reason this solution looks appealing for some of us is that it is intuitive and readable. It's just multiplying a [2x1] column vector with a [1x5] row vector to get the [2x5] matrix etc...

Comment: yes, for "some of us" was good said :D cause when i am trying to rewrite it exactly on my problem i still get a inner matrix dimensions error..:D..but anyway thank you very much as well..go to try to play with that..i want atleast understand that..:] thank you very much

Comment: got it..inversion by another element :]..ok i think i understand it..thank you both guys. i think i will use one of those possibilities many times in next coding..it helped me a lot

Comment: Remember to use `.'`, not `'`. The vectors could be complex!